# Understanding SevSeg

Tags: library, data-type

I need to write a library for a display I created with eight segments. So, I decided to try to use SevSeg (https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg) as a starting off point. It can't be *that* different, right?

Well, I think I have hit a roadblock that indicates I must basically do everything from scratch. Here is how the information on what segments correspond to letters are stored in SevSeg:

```
 // The codes below indicate which segments must be 
//illuminated to display each number.

static const byte digitCodeMap[] = {
  //     GFEDCBA  Segments      7-segment map:
  B00111111, // 0   "0"          AAA
  B00000110, // 1   "1"         F   B
  B01011011, // 2   "2"         F   B
  B01001111, // 3   "3"          GGG
  B01100110, // 4   "4"         E   C
  B01101101, // 5   "5"         E   C
  B01111101, // 6   "6"          DDD
  B00000111, // 7   "7"
  B01111111, // 8   "8"
  B01101111, // 9   "9"
  B01110111, // 65  'A'
  B01111100, // 66  'b'
  B00111001, // 67  'C'
  B01011110, // 68  'd'
  B01111001, // 69  'E'
  B01110001, // 70  'F'
  B00111101, // 71  'G'
  B01110110, // 72  'H'
  B00000110, // 73  'I'
  B00001110, // 74  'J'
  B01110110, // 75  'K'  Same as 'H'
  B00111000, // 76  'L'
  B00000000, // 77  'M'  NO DISPLAY
  B01010100, // 78  'n'
  B00111111, // 79  'O'
  B01110011, // 80  'P'
  B01100111, // 81  'q'
  B01010000, // 82  'r'
  B01101101, // 83  'S'
  B01111000, // 84  't'
  B00111110, // 85  'U'
  B00111110, // 86  'V'  Same as 'U'
  B00000000, // 87  'W'  NO DISPLAY
  B01110110, // 88  'X'  Same as 'H'
  B01101110, // 89  'y'
  B01011011, // 90  'Z'  Same as '2'
  B00000000, // 32  ' '  BLANK
  B01000000, // 45  '-'  DASH
};
```

As you can see this is a one dimensional array of 8-byte binaries that encode the segment. I don't understand the purpose of the B0 at the beginning of each byte. Could I use the 0 column to encode my eighth segment?

Am I right to assume this will change everything about the code and maybe I should start from scratch with a 2-D array?

This is roughly what I want:

```
//  ABCDEFGH  Segments      8-segment map:
  11000011, // 0   "0"       A BBBBB H
  10000000, // 1   "1"       A C   D H
  01011010, // 2   "2"       A C   D H
  11101010, // 3   "3"       A  C D  H
  00110101, // 4   "4"       A  E F  H
  01011010, // 5   "5"       A E   F H
  11101110, // 6   "6"       A E   F H
  01011000, // 7   "7"       A GGGGG H
  01111110, // 8   "8"
  01100101, // 9   "9"
  11111101, // 10  "A"
  10001110, // 11  "b"
  11000010, // 12  "C"
  00001111, // 13  "d"
```

What data type should I use for the array? Would byte work since I'm not using the B0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand the purpose of the B0 at the beginning of each byte.

That's just Arduino's rather weird way of doing binary constants. For example, in the file binary.h are lines and lines of stuff like this:

```
#define B1011 11
#define B01011 11
#define B001011 11
#define B0001011 11
#define B00001011 11
#define B1100 12
#define B01100 12
#define B001100 12
#define B0001100 12
#define B00001100 12
```

A better way is to use standard C++ constants, eg.

```
0b00001100
```

instead of:

```
B00001100
```

---

> Could I use the 0 column to encode my eighth segment?

Yes, they are just bytes, so you can use all 8 bits.